# Why don't Bower components load unless moved into /scripts folder?

Tags: angularjs, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

I used the yoeoman Angular generator to create a new project.   When I started the server using the gulp file below, I received Angular module injector errors until I moved all files in the bower_components folder into the app/scripts.   Is this by design?   When I had my scripts references in my index.html pointing up one level outside the app folder to the bower_component folder, they were not being loaded.

This is the command I start my server with:

```
gulp serve  

    // Generated on 2015-11-06 using generator-angular 0.14.0
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var openURL = require('open');
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');

var rimraf = require('rimraf');
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

var yeoman = {
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
  dist: 'dist'
};

var paths = {
  scripts: [yeoman.app + '/scripts/**/*.js'],
  styles: [yeoman.app + '/styles/**/*.scss'],
  test: ['test/spec/**/*.js'],
  testRequire: [
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
    yeoman.app + '/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'test/mock/**/*.js',
    'test/spec/**/*.js'
  ],
  karma: 'karma.conf.js',
  views: {
    main: yeoman.app + '/index.html',
    files: [yeoman.app + '/views/**/*.html']
  }
};

////////////////////////
// Reusable pipelines //
////////////////////////

var lintScripts = lazypipe()
  .pipe($.jshint, '.jshintrc')
  .pipe($.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

var styles = lazypipe()
  .pipe($.sass, {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    precision: 10
  })
  .pipe($.autoprefixer, 'last 1 version')
  .pipe(gulp.dest, '.tmp/styles');

///////////
// Tasks //
///////////

gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.styles)
    .pipe(styles());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(lintScripts());
});

gulp.task('clean:tmp', function (cb) {
  rimraf('./.tmp', cb);
});

gulp.task('start:client', ['start:server', 'styles'], function () {
  openURL('http://localhost:9000');
});

gulp.task('start:server', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: [yeoman.app, '.tmp'],
    livereload: true,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    port: 9000
  });
});

gulp.task('start:server:test', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: ['test', yeoman.app, '.tmp'],
    livereload: true,
    port: 9001
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  $.watch(paths.styles)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe(styles())
    .pipe($.connect.reload());

  $.watch(paths.views.files)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.connect.reload());

  $.watch(paths.scripts)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe(lintScripts())
    .pipe($.connect.reload());

  $.watch(paths.test)
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe(lintScripts());

  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['bower']);
});

gulp.task('serve', function (cb) {
  runSequence('clean:tmp',
    ['lint:scripts'],
    ['start:client'],
    'watch', cb);
});

gulp.task('serve:prod', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: [yeoman.dist],
    livereload: true,
    port: 9000
  });
});

gulp.task('test', ['start:server:test'], function () {
  var testToFiles = paths.testRequire.concat(paths.scripts, paths.test);
  return gulp.src(testToFiles)
    .pipe($.karma({
      configFile: paths.karma,
      action: 'watch'
    }));
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('bower', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: yeoman.app + '/bower_components',
      ignorePath: '..'
    }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app + '/views'));
});

///////////
// Build //
///////////

gulp.task('clean:dist', function (cb) {
  rimraf('./dist', cb);
});

gulp.task('client:build', ['html', 'styles'], function () {
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

  return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
    .pipe($.useref.assets({searchPath: [yeoman.app, '.tmp']}))
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.minifyCss({cache: true}))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.useref.restore())
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/views/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/views'));
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
        optimizationLevel: 5,
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/images'));
});

gulp.task('copy:extras', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/*/.*', { dot: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean:dist'], function () {
  runSequence(['images', 'copy:extras', 'copy:fonts', 'client:build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Comment: generally, yes, this is by design. usually you'll use a build script (gulp/grunt) that copies the minified file from bower_components to your dist folder. The advantage of this is if you needed to deploy your client-side code separately from your server-side, you could without changing too much or sending the entire bower-components folder when you only need a single file from each subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gulp-connect middleware` to connect `bower-components` folder which is outside of app folder.

If you run `gulp serve` then you need to replace

```
gulp.task('start:server', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: [yeoman.app, '.tmp'],
    livereload: true,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    port: 9000
  });
});
```

With this one

```
gulp.task('start:server', function() {
  $.connect.server({
    root: [yeoman.app, '.tmp'],
    livereload: true,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    port: 9000,
    middleware: function(connect) {
        return [connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('bower_components'))];
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can you clarify where this should be added?